# substring manipulation

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm in a process converting html to XML, and all works fine but I'm struggling a bit on converting my original path structure to a new one.

Below example explains what I want to achieve :

What I have now (simplified example) :

```
<links>
<link>../../../folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/somefile.png</link>
<link>../../../foldera/folderb/folder/some_other_file.gif</link>
<link>folder_x/yet_another_file.jpg</link>
</links>
```

What I like to get :

```
<links>
<link>somefile.png</link>
<link>some_other_file.gif</link>
<link>yet_another_file.jpg</link>
</links>
```

Or in other words, what's the simplest approach using xslt (2) to get the string after the final "/" in my text

Thanks for any advice on this !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="link">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., '/')[last()]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

plus the identity transformation of course e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:function name="xfn:substringAfterLast">
  <xsl:param name="arg"/> 
  <xsl:param name="delim"/> 

  <xsl:sequence select="replace ($arg,concat('^.*',xfn:escapeForRegex($delim)),'')"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="xfn:escapeForRegex" >              
    <xsl:param name="arg"/> 
   <xsl:sequence select="replace($arg, '(\.|\[|\]|\\|\||\-|\^|\$|\?|\*|\+|\{|\}|\(|\))','\\$1')"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="xfn:substringAfterLast('../../../folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/somefile.png', '/')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

This also requires an additional namespace declaration, of course.

Comment: Agreed :-) lots better to use the tokenize solution suggested by Martin Honnen!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this does not work, see the comments

You could use the `substring-after` function to achieve this. Iterate over the `link` nodes and the path will be

```
<xsl:variable name="lastPart" select="substring-after(text(.), '/')"/>
```

`$lastPart` will now contain whatever is to the right of the last `/` in the string. If there is no such character this will return the empty string so you may need to provide an extra check for that.

Comment: Better check your references... http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-after

Comment: "The substring-after function returns the substring of the first argument string that follows the **first occurrence** of the second argument string..."